# Estimating trunk rotation using frontal and sagittal views

Tags: measurements, biomechanics

I am doing an experiment regarding elbow flexion's effect on peak sprinting velocity and we want to measure trunk rotation and shoulder rotation during our trials. We don't have an overhead camera so we have to make do with cameras in the sagittal and frontal planes. Is there a way of estimating the trunk rotation and shoulder rotation this way? Perhaps using angular area and estimating based on the known width of the participants and distance from the camera (although my geometry skills aren't good enough to find a closed form for any such equation)? I can't think of any other way to do it. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A friend had to measure limb movement and put white discs with black crosses to follow with imaging software - coding will be fun...

Comment: I run 25 miles a week. i have been injured and had to wear custom sneakers. they tested me running while a camera was measuring my stride, gait, etc. so there already is commercial system available.